# Best way to have a parameter which returns values and null

Tags: oracle, plsql

First question is do both of these work:

```
WHERE PROJECT_ID IN ('&PROJECT_ID', NULL)

(PROJECT_ID = '&PROJECT_ID' OR PROJECT_ID IS NULL)
```

And second is if so which is best or is there a better / working alternative?

Essentially want all project id's and records with null to be returned.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `WHERE PROJECT_ID IS NULL OR PROJECT_ID = '&PROJECT_ID'` is not that cumbersome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WHERE PROJECT_ID = '&PROJECT_ID' 
AND PROJECT_ID IS NOT NULL